# Long build times due to copying duplicate references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, prism, mef

I have a large WPF MEF PRISM solution (100+ projects), and our build times are around the 2 minute mark on quad core 8 GB machines.

I output all binaries to the same output path "..\Bin" so that our MEF bootstrapper can scan and find all assemblies.

In troubleshooting the build times, I've noticed that each project that references a core Infastructure library will copy this binary to the output directory, resulting in multiple copies for the exact same file.  I feel that the actual compile is quick, but the amount of duplicate copying is crippling my build times.

Is there any way to tell the project not to copy references if the same version of the file already exists in the output directory?  I already have secondary SLN files with a smaller project collection, and this helps most people cut build times down.

Comment: did you try parallel builds feature ? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx

Comment: @Amitd I'll give it a shot, but I think I'm I/O bound by the copying.  Building actually seems quick, it's the duplication of copying files to the same directory that is slowing me down.  This would actually be preferable if I was copying each project to it's own bin directory.

Comment: you may have to write custom msbuild script to build each project in its own directory.Then copy over the main project output to the main solution output directory.

Comment: Also check this related SO question + article in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771133/can-you-do-parallel-incremental-building-on-a-list-of-projects

Answer (score 3):

Copying files in Windows is *very* fast, a memory-to-memory copy thanks to the file system cache.  Especially so in a build since the files are freshly created so their data is always present in the cache.  The actual write to disk does not occur until later, when the cache manager lazily writes the file data to the disk.  Which operates in the background and cannot slow down the build.  The only case where a file copy will be slow is when the file system cache is filled to capacity and must wait for the slow disk write to make more space.

Copying the same file more than once, even if it didn't get created by the build, is similarly fast.  You only pay for reading the file the first time.  After which any subsequent copy always uses the cached file data.

There is no reasonable scenario where a .NET solution could fill the cache to capacity, and make it slow, on a machine with 8 gigabytes of RAM.  The cache should be at least 2 gigabytes.  Writing a .NET solution that generates 2 gigabytes of code and resources is not reasonably possible.

You are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's pretty solution, but you can let your Infrastructure to copy to output directory and everywhere it is referenced you can set `CopyLocal` attribute of particular reference to False. I don't say it's the only option but it could do what you want. I just want to help.

EDIT:

I don't know if you do so, but if you don't you can have `xcopy` in `post-build` to copy those dlls you need for MEF to that output directory. In that case you could avoid these difficulties.